# OneNote2013-Reference to undeclared namespace prefix:'one' error

Tags: excel, vba, onenote

started with OneNote vba today, so got samples program over the net to try out. Made basic changes to the following (which creates a new page in OneNote) as I have OneNote 2013. But every program I try to run returns the error -
Reference to undeclared namespace prefix:'one' error (for the lines marked in bold).
Can anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here. I need to get an assignment done through which I could run OCR for a printscreen and get the data back to excel but to start with that i thought it would be a good thing to get the basics right. It has taken an entire day and I still cannot make anything work.
By the way references for Onenote 15.0 object library and xml v6.0 have been made. I'm a beginner in VBA and any help is appreciated.

```
Sub CreateNewPage()
    ' Connect to OneNote 2013.
    ' To see the results of the code,
    ' you'll want to ensure the OneNote 2013 user
    ' interface is visible.
    Dim OneNote As OneNote.Application
    Set OneNote = New OneNote.Application
    
    ' Get all of the Notebook nodes.
    Dim nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
    Set nodes = GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes(OneNote)
    If Not nodes Is Nothing Then
        ' Get the first OneNote Notebook in the XML document.
        Dim node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
        Set node = nodes(0)
        Dim noteBookName As String
        noteBookName = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
        
        ' Get the ID for the Notebook so the code can retrieve
        ' the list of sections.
        Dim notebookID As String
        notebookID = node.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
        
        ' Load the XML for the Sections for the Notebook requested.
        Dim sectionsXml As String
        OneNote.GetHierarchy notebookID, hsSections, sectionsXml, xs2013
        
        Dim secDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
        Set secDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
        If secDoc.LoadXML(sectionsXml) Then
            ' select the Section nodes
            Dim secNodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList
            Set secNodes = secDoc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Section")
            
            If Not secNodes Is Nothing Then
                ' Get the first section.
                Dim secNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                Set secNode = secNodes(0)
                
                Dim sectionName As String
                sectionName = secNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("name").Text
                Dim sectionID As String
                sectionID = secNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("ID").Text
                
                ' Create a new blank Page in the first Section
                ' using the default format.
                Dim newPageID As String
                OneNote.CreateNewPage sectionID, newPageID, npsDefault
                
                ' Get the contents of the page.
                Dim outXML As String
                OneNote.GetPageContent newPageID, outXML, piAll, xs2013
                
                Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
                Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
                ' Load Page's XML into a MSXML2.DOMDocument object.
                If doc.LoadXML(outXML) Then
                    ' Get Page Node.
                    Dim pageNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    Set pageNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//one:Page")

                    ' Find the Title element.
                    Dim titleNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    Set titleNode = doc.SelectSingleNode("//one:Page/one:Title/one:OE/one:T")
                    
                    ' Get the CDataSection where OneNote store's the Title's text.
                    Dim cdataChild As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    Set cdataChild = titleNode.SelectSingleNode("text()")
                    
                    ' Change the title in the local XML copy.
                    cdataChild.Text = "A Page Created from VBA"
                    ' Write the update to OneNote.
                    OneNote.UpdatePageContent doc.XML
                    
                    Dim newElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement
                    Dim newNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
                    
                    ' Create Outline node.
                    Set newElement = doc.createElement("one:Outline")
                    Set newNode = pageNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create OEChildren.
                    Set newElement = doc.createElement("one:OEChildren")
                    Set newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create OE.
                    Set newElement = doc.createElement("one:OE")
                    Set newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    ' Create TE.
                    Set newElement = doc.createElement("one:T")
                    Set newNode = newNode.appendChild(newElement)
                    
                    ' Add the text for the Page's content.
                    Dim cd As MSXML2.IXMLDOMCDATASection
                    Set cd = doc.createCDATASection("Text added to a new OneNote page via VBA.")

                    newNode.appendChild cd
                 
                    
                    ' Update OneNote with the new content.
                    OneNote.UpdatePageContent doc.XML
                    
                    ' Print out information about the update.
                    Debug.Print "A new page was created in "
                    Debug.Print "Section " & sectionName & " in"
                    Debug.Print "Notebook " & noteBookName & "."
                    Debug.Print "Contents of new Page:"
                    
                    Debug.Print doc.XML
                End If
            Else
                MsgBox "OneNote 2013 Section nodes not found."
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "OneNote 2013 Section XML Data failed to load."
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "OneNote 2013 XML Data failed to load."
    End If
    
End Sub

Private Function GetAttributeValueFromNode(node As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode, attributeName As String) As String
    If node.Attributes.getNamedItem(attributeName) Is Nothing Then
        GetAttributeValueFromNode = "Not found."
    Else
        GetAttributeValueFromNode = node.Attributes.getNamedItem(attributeName).Text
    End If
End Function

Private Function GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes(OneNote As OneNote.Application) As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList

  ' Get the XML that represents the OneNote notebooks available.
    Dim notebookXml As String
    ' OneNote fills notebookXml with an XML document providing information
    ' about what OneNote notebooks are available.
    ' You want all the data and thus are providing an empty string
    ' for the bstrStartNodeID parameter.
    OneNote.GetHierarchy "", hsNotebooks, notebookXml, xs2013
    
    ' Use the MSXML Library to parse the XML.
    Dim doc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    Set doc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
    
    If doc.LoadXML(notebookXml) Then
        **Set GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes = doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//one:Notebook")**
    Else
        Set GetFirstOneNoteNotebookNodes = Nothing
    End If
End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
doc.SetProperty "SelectionNamespaces", "xmlns:one='http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/2013/onenote'"
```

before you call the SelectNodes method, to specify your namespace.

Answer (score 0):

you need to specify a namespace. "one:" is not a namespace, it is just an alias for one.

your XML document should have something like xmlns:one="**http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/onenote/12/2004/onenote**"

at the top.

the namespace is what I have bolded above.
check the MSXML API docs to see how to specify a namespace when you do a query.

Comment: yeah had to read a lot, thanks for pointing in the right direction, now i have a better understanding of this
ps sorry for an extremely late reply